# testProguardFiles ignores my rules. Unable to run Espresso tests against the release build type

Tags: android, proguard, android-espresso

I'd love to run my Android instrumented tests against the release build type. Here is what I did.

Changed the test build type as recommended [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#change-the-test-build-type):

```
android {

    testBuildType "release"
}
```

Created `proguard-test-rules.pro` in the `app/` directory and added it to the release build type section:

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-test-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

`proguard-test-rules.pro` contains the only line:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
```

However, when I run the command `./gradlew clean connectedMyFlavorReleaseAndroidTest`, I see the following errors in the console output:

```
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
```

So it looks like `proguard-test-rules.pro` is ignored. Why? 
Sure I can use [this solution](https://gist.github.com/knappador/1c7824979e1b21061b0b#gistcomment-1706340), but I just wonder why `proguard-test-rules.pro` is ignored. I also tried `proguardFile 'proguard-test-rules.pro'` which didn't work either.

**My Gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Comment: `dontwarn` is not enough. Have you tried with `-keep okio.** { *; }`?

Comment: dontwarn was enough for me. The point is that `proguard-test-rules.pro` is ignored. When I add `-dontwarn okio.**` to `proguard-rules.pro` (which is applied like this: `release { proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' }`, I don't see the warnings about `okio`

Comment: Did you add .pro to your file tree in your build file?

Comment: My answer below worked for me when i came across the same issue. Please let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: Whatever the rationale was to take this approach, the whole approach is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

For Android to read .pro files you need to tell it to accept it:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37104292

```
buildTypes {

 release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    //Something like this
    proguardFiles fileTree(dir: 'vendor', include: ['*.pro']).asList().toArray()

    testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-test-rules.pro'
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work for me. The testProguardFile still ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This took me quite a while to solve; it does seem that for whatever reason recent versions of gradle/proGuard seem to ignore that setting. (testProguardFile("your-file.pro"))

Found a really clean and simple way to do it using some conditional logic inside your release.

Below is the version in kotlin dsl, so build.gradle.kts but no doubt there will be the Groovy equivalent if using regular build.gradle:

```
     getByName("release") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            isDebuggable = false
            // any other release config as normal
            isMinifyEnabled = !gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.contains("AndroidTest") }
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }
```

Explaning what this does:

```
isMinifyEnabled = !gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.contains("AndroidTest") }
```

This is saying DON'T MINIFY if the gradle task that kicked off the build has "AndroidTest" in it somewhere e.g. assembleReleaseAndroidTest

Confirmed this still minifies the release apk, and now any minification for the test apk is totally turned off, and all unit tests now run fine on the release apk.